# how do I move up a division a little

Tags: html, css

I want to move up my division a little, I tried putting top: 20; but it doesnt work.

Here's the css:

```
.col_seventh {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: right;
    padding: -100px;
    width: 30%;
    top: 20;
}

.box7 {
    background-color: #14bcc8;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.box8 {
    background-color: #ff7e70;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: show us your html too...

Comment: 1/ please show HTML
2/ what are you trying to do with negative padding?
3/ `top` property has to got a unit, like *px* or *em*

Comment: Not enough information to give an answer. Where's the HTML? What division? Etc. A shot in the dark is that you need to add `position: relative;` to `.col_seventh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend generally trying to use `margin` and `padding` for small adjustments to element positioning.

`top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right` require a unit of measurement (like px) and are designed to work with the `position` property. Using these methods can create other problems (like reading order not matching DOM order or issues on mobile/responsive sites), and as such they should be used only when genuinely needed.